# SQL Server is not printing the whole text

Tags: sql, sql-server, powershell, sql-server-2012

I have this SQL Server script and this is working fine. The only issue I have is the "Source" value is not printing the whole thing in my txt file for some reason.

I would be really appreciated if I can get any help or suggestion on how to fix it and show the whole source text in my txt ouput file instead of having ... after a few character.

[image]

```
        -- Printing Adding Records which are exists in Temp_Hold_Inv Table and Not exists in Hold_Inv Table
        
        SELECT 'Adding: '+XX.Source+' '+XX.Type AS Result
        FROM (
            Select  * from (
                SELECT Source, Type
                FROM Temp_Hold_Inv Thi
                WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Hold_Inv Hi WHERE  Thi.Source = Hi.Source)
                AND Thi.Source <> 'NOT FOUND'
                AND LEN(TRIM(ISNULL(Thi.Source, ''))) > 0
                UNION ALL
                SELECT  Source, Type 
                FROM Temp_Hold_Inv Thi
                WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Hold_Inv Hi WHERE  Thi.Source = Hi.Source)
                AND Thi.Source = 'NOT FOUND'
                UNION ALL
                SELECT  Source, Type 
                FROM Temp_Hold_Inv Thi
                WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Hold_Inv Hi WHERE  Thi.Source = Hi.Source)
                AND LEN(TRIM(ISNULL(Thi.Source, ''))) = 0) T1
            except select * from (SELECT Source, [Type] FROM Daily_Proc) T2
        ) XX
        GO"


        Invoke-Sqlcmd -Query $query2 -ServerInstance $Global:Server -Database $Global:Database -username $SQLusername -password $SQLpass -ErrorAction Stop | Out-File -filePath $Global:QueryLogPath
```

Comment: What tool/code are you using to write the query results to the output file?

Comment: @DanGuzman Hi, This SQL script is inside my PowerShell Script that is running daily from Task Scheduler.

Comment: The issue is with the powershell code, not the query.  Add the ps code to your question. Added the powershell tag.

Comment: Just a guess does explicitly casting the contatenation as varchar(max) affect it at all?

Comment: @DanGuzman ok, I have updated the code. Pls check. $Global:QueryLogPath variableis my local path.

Comment: @Stu I'm not sure what you mean. Could you please show me example?

Comment: Try specifying a `-Width` parameter for `Out-File` with a value of the longest value you expect.

Comment: More to rule it out than anything else, does `select Convert(varchar(max), Concat('Adding: ', XX.Source, ' ', XX.Type)) as Result` affect it?

Comment: DanGuzman @Stu ok thanks both for the suggestion. I've modified and let see if it work. Thank you